# format currency - remove decimals

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I need to convert from cents to euros

```
{
ref: "1dsdsd",
title: "XXXXXX",

price: 92820
},
{
ref: "2ddsds",
title: "XXXXXX",

price: 12830
},
{
ref: "3dsds",
title: "XXXXXXX",
price: 885
} 
]
```

if the value is 885 cents, we should read 8.85euros, but
the values returned by the webservice are not consistent : 2, 3 , 5 digits

my solution does not allow to return a value in euros by removing the extra decimals

```
extension Int {
    func format() -> String {
        let double = Double(self) / 100
        return String(format: "€ %.02f", double)
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIoJx.jpg)

Comment: Well your biggest issue is that you're not really formatting currency, at all. You're hard coding the €, and you're harding coding a `.` as the decimal separator, even though some (most?) European countries use the `,` as a decimal separator. You should use `NSNumberFormatter`, with the correct local, to fix all this.

Comment: Your issue is not clear. Your code will convert `92820` into `€ 928.20` and `885` into `€ 8.85`. What do you want instead?

Comment: I agree, but this is how the data is returned from the web service. I am having a hard time with it as well

Answer (score 2):

Don't try todo this with your own code as there are too many variables to take account of. Instead use a [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter), set its `numberStyle` to the appropriate currency style you need.

If your code is not running in a locale where the currency is euros you can set the formatter's `locale` property to one where it is – **don't** to to change the currency symbol by setting the `currencyCode` or related properties, a locale carries more information about the layout.

Your values are in integer cents, a good choice for currency values, unfortunately `NumberFormatter` expects the unit to be euros (or pound etc.). You can address this in two ways (a) pre-divide the number by 100 before passing it to the formatter or (b) set the formatter's `multiplier` property to `0.01` (*Note: in this latter case you must still pass the number to be formatted as floating point (e.g. `Double`) or the cents will get truncated, this is a feature/bug of `NumberFormatter`*)